# Arellano Bond in Stata: very high p-values when using the robust twostep estimator

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, panel-data, dynamic-regression

I am doing a panel regression with N=21, T= 28 with 8 regressors which is dynamic in structure (includes a lag of the dependent variable).

Using the robust one step estimator by Arellano & Bond, implemented in xtabond, Stata, I get mostly low p-values associated with all parameters. When using the twostep estimator with the vce(robust) option, almost all of the p-values are > 0.9.

Does anyone have some idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hard to say without information on the context, but you should be aware that Nickell bias will be quite small with a panel that long.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware. There is little difference in parameters whether I use GMM or OLS. I am just curious of the result, and not so much in estimating the parameters per se.